# iterate through sublists, compare and print what is missing

Tags: python

I am trying to iterate through sublists and return name of the element that doesn't match with today's date. Example:

```
x = [['service_2023_01_10', 'service_2023_01_11', 'service_2023_01_12'], ['forms_2023_01_10', 'forms_2023_01_11']]

today = '2023_01_12'
```

and my result should be:

```
result = [[], ['forms']]
```

because elements that contain 'forms' doesn't have today's date in it.

This was my solution for similar task but I can't make it work for this one:

```
result = [[e.split("_")[0] for e in sublist if "_".join(e.split("_")[-3:]) == today] if any([ "_".join(e.split("_")[-3:]) == today for e in sublist]) else [] for sublist in x]
```

this one returns: `[['service'], []]` but it should be the opposite.
Can you help me with it. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by the opposite? this output: `[['service', 'service'], ['forms', 'forms']]` ?

Comment: I changed the result code. The one provided should work fine as I said before

Comment: @SimonLundberg x is a list that contains 2 sublists.

Comment: Yeah sorry I misread that (on my phone). But it's still not clear to me what you actually want to happen. You want the non-date part of the string of a list where the date is in the string, or an empty array if not? Why do you want `[[], ['forms']]` instead of `[None, 'forms']`?

Comment: Can the "matching" sub-lists contain multiple different types of strings?

Comment: RomanPerekhrest answered my question. Maybe [None, 'forms'] would be ok too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using `any` and `str.partition` functions:

```
x = [['service_2023_01_10', 'service_2023_01_11', 'service_2023_01_12'], ['forms_2023_01_10', 'forms_2023_01_11']]
today = '2023_01_12'
res = [[] if any(today in w for w in sub_l) else [sub_l[0].partition('_')[0]] for sub_l in x]
print(res)
```

---

```
[[], ['forms']]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired behavior with `next` method of generator that finds first `today` in string. Generator allows you not to check every element in sublist but just find first one.

Also your date is always in yyyy_mm_dd format, you can hardcode 11 symbols slice.

```
x = [['service_2023_01_10', 'service_2023_01_11', 'service_2023_01_12'], ['forms_2023_01_10', 'forms_2023_01_11']]
today = '2023_01_12'

result = [[] if next((file for file in sublist if today in file), None) else sublist[0][:-11] for sublist in x]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[], 'forms']
```

Comment: I would recommend changing 'sublist[0][:-11]' to sublist[0].lsplit("_")[0] since yours does not work in all cases

Comment: @The6thSense well, if we are not sure that all of our list elements contain some date in it then of course you are right. However deksa89's example shows us some code with all elements containing date in filename using same format (as I mentioned in my answer).